# How do you politely correct a higher-up who misread your email?

Tags: management, new-job, scheduling

I've arranged a call with someone from a different company. I am new to the company and this man I am scheduling to call is the co-CEO of our main partner company.

I wrote 15.30 as the call time and he emailed back 'Yes, that time works, 12.30 pm, give us a call through Skype'. Now, I'm quite confused as to what the call time is, and since I can't call him at 12.30 pm, how do I verify that the call time is 15.30 and correct him politely? Anything I've written so far sounds very 'know-it-all' and 'you made a mistake, fix it - demanding'.

I want to avoid this and wish to sound as polite as possible...

I feel as if I'm probably overthinking the answer, but would appreciate any advice.

Comment: what about "Dear Sir - could we double-check the time the client said is 1530 .. 330pm today."   How's that?

Comment: are you both in same time zone? May be they already converted 15:30 into their own time zone.

Comment: @PagMax Along with that thought, is it common in the CEO's culture to use 24 hour time formats? Could be he's not used to that and mistakenly read 1230.

Comment: @Dan I don’t think one format is common than other and I don’t think CEOs has their own culture regarding that.

Comment: In America, 24 hour format is uncommon except in the military/government sector. In Europe, I believe some countries use 24 hour format over the 12. Unsure if that has any impact to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Hi co-Ceo,
>
> I just wanted to clarify that the time of the call is 15:30 as your
>   reply has stated 12:30

Nothing know-it-all about it, you're just clarifying a detail.

Comment: Add the time zone to this clarification just to avoid further confusion, for example "15:30 PDT"

Comment: @Peter That be kind of silly, and maybe "know it all" to include the time zone if they are in the same city/state. It's unclear from the OP if they are in different timezones.

Comment: Yeah OP should not add timezone unless they know for sure that they are in different timezone. I would as my coworkers about the timezone (since op is new he said) before sending.